# How can I save test case result in a variable whether it is passed or not after the test case execution is done?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, visual-studio-2019

I am using selenium webdriver in visual studio Using NUNIT. The code of test case is

I want to Log that test case is passed or fail in a variable right after the test case is executed.How can I achieve that?

Comment: Although you indicate you are using NUnit, your sample code isn't using NUnit attributes.

Comment: @Charlie keeping in view my reference code, please guide.

Answer (score 3):

### NUnit

Assume you use NUnit (because what's in the question looks like MSTest), you could write custom [`IWrapTestMethod`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ICommandWrapper-Interface) attribute to extend the test command. The attribute gives you an opportunity to inspect on the test and test result before and after each test run:

```
// I don't know where your variable is, so just use this dummy class with
// some dummy static properties.
class TestResultKeeper
{
    public static TestResult TestResult { get; set; }
    public static ResultState ResultState => TestResult?.ResultState ?? ResultState.Failure;
    public static bool IsPassed => ResultState == ResultState.Success;
    public static Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

// Custom NUnit 3 attribute to extend test method
public class LogTestAttribute : Attribute, IWrapTestMethod
{
    public TestCommand Wrap(TestCommand command)
    {
        // Wrap test command
        return new LogTestResultCommand(command);
    }
}

class LogTestResultCommand : DelegatingTestCommand
{
    public LogTestResultCommand(TestCommand innerCommand)
        : base(innerCommand)
    {

    }

    public override TestResult Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = innerCommand.Execute(context);

            // Set test result to TestResultKeeper

            TestResultKeeper.TestResult = result;
            TestResultKeeper.Exception = null;

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Exception thrown from test. Test failed.

            TestResultKeeper.TestResult = null;
            TestResultKeeper.Exception = e.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Test, LogTest]
public void Test1()
{
    Assert.Fail();
}

[Test, LogTest]
public void Test2()
{
    Assert.Pass();
}
```

### MSTest

Assume your test is written in MSTest (as per your example), you could [create a new test method attribute](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-customize-test-execution.htm) and derive from `TestMethodAttribute`, and do similar things as above:

```
class TestResultKeeper
{
    public static TestResult TestResult { get; set; }
    public static UnitTestOutcome TestOutcome => TestResult?.Outcome ?? UnitTestOutcome.Failed;
    public static bool IsPassed => TestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed;
    public static Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

public class LogTestTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        var testResult = base.Execute(testMethod)[0];


        TestResultKeeper.TestResult = testResult;
        TestResultKeeper.Exception = testResult.TestFailureException;

        return new[] { testResult };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[LogTestTestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
}
```

Comment: @Amna I created a dummy `TestResultKeeper` because I don't know where you'd like to save test result. You can change it to somewhere else.

Comment: could you please update MStest as well just like you did in Nunit?

Comment: @Amna MSTest example is already in the answer. See the `MSTest` title.

Comment: In `MStest` it is mentioned do similar things as above. I want to know which things? @weichch

Comment: @Amna Oh, by that I just meant "using your own types to extend the test framework". As you can see in the example in MSTest section, I used `LogTestTestMethodAttribute` which is derived from `TestMethodAttribute`, and `LogTestTestMethodAttribute` is similar to `LogTestAttribute` in NUnit. The example should already work.

Comment: Using Mstest code showing some exception like 1) `public static UnitTestOutcome TestOutcome => TestResult?.Outcome ?? UnitTestOutcome.Failed`; **Exception : "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TestOutcome?' and 'UnitTestOutcome** 2) `public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)` Exception : **LogTestTestMethod.Execute(ITestMethod)': no suitable method found to override**

Comment: 3) `var testResult = base.Execute(testMethod)[0];` exception : **Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'Execute** 4)  `return new[] { testResult }`; Exception : **Cannot implicitly convert type '?[]' to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestResult[]**

Comment: 5) `public class LogTestTestMethod : TestMethodAttribute` Exception : **LogTestTestMethod': cannot derive from sealed type 'TestMethodAttribute**

Comment: @Amna Looks like you are using MSTest v1, and my code is MSTest v2. MSTest V1 has been discontinued, and not able to extend easily. Given MSTest v2 offers more (including extendability), I'd suggest you move to v2. It would be a trivial change https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-to-mstest-v2/.

Comment: No, I am using MStest v2.1.0.

Comment: As per the source code of `TestMethodAttribute` https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/master/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Attributes/VSTestAttributes.cs#L68, the attribute is not `sealed` in v2, so you might need to double check if you are using v2.

Comment: `TestkeeprResult` class is saving test results?

Comment: @Amna `TestResultKeeper` class is an example of how test results / test context data could be saved to variables as per your question. It is a dummy class.

Answer (score 1):

For **NUnit** you can access the result and other details of the test using properties found in **TestContext.CurrentContext**.

For your problem you can add the following check to the test teardown method

```
if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status == TestStatus.Passed) { .... }
```

*Edit to include **MSTest**:*

For MSTest add the following property to your test class

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

Then use it by adding the following to *TestCleanup*

```
if(TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed) { .... }
```